# Run time of algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I am trying to figure out the run time of the following algorithm. 
I argue it is O(n) because the inner loop does not depend on the outer loop.
So we could have O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) which equals O(n)
Is this correct? I'm not sure my logic is correct and I cannot figure out how to analyze is correctly.

The algorithm is finding the largest elements to the left of a list of elements.
Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = {4,3,2,10,4,8,9,1};
    int[] p = new int[a.length];
    ArrayDeque<Integer> previousIndex = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++){
        while (!previousIndex.isEmpty() && a[previousIndex.peek()] <= a[i]){
            previousIndex.pop();
        }
        if (previousIndex.isEmpty()) { 
          p[i] = 0;
        } else {
          p[i] = previousIndex.peek();
        }
        previousIndex.push(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length ; i++){
        System.out.println(p[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes O(n)+O(n) is the same as O(n), however, you have a `while` loop inside the `for` loop. How many times can that loop run? That may affect the answer.

Comment: This is not a complete function, so the question is impossible to answer. What is the algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: @Matt Exactly, it can run n-1 times

Comment: @user1998581 Then it's `O(n^2)`

Comment: This is not O(n) + O(n) case, because the while loop runs n times and so whatever is within it runs n*k times, where k is the number of operations within while loop.

Comment: Yes I agree with ZouZou it looks like O(n^2) in that case.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... back to the drawing board... thanks!

Comment: The code presented will always do the same thing.  Its best case is the same as its worst case is `O(1)`.  It really does not matter what you specify `args` as, the runtime will be exactly the same.

Comment: @emory thanks! I need an O(n) algorithm to do this problem... so I have to figure out a new one!

Comment: You say you're finding "the largest elements to the left of a list", but it seems to be finding the first element to the left that's larger, or zero if none are larger, of each index?

Comment: @user1998581 what do you need an O(n) algorithm for? schoolwork.  Step 1:  Define the input of the algorithm.  As presented the algorithm input is `args` which is never actually referenced.  Step 2:  Define the unit of work - which I assume to be `System.out.println(p[i]);`

Comment: @emory yes for school but I am not asking for the solution, just asking if my logic was correct or incorrect. I only put the function in a main so that it could run. The list I am using is a which I defined on my own as a test case. I have the system.out for my own testing.

Answer (score 1):

This is O(N) for though you have a loop within a loop, the total number of times the inner loop will be executed can never be more than the total number of times that

```
previousIndex.push(i);
```

is called, which is a.length (or N)

Comment: For a very similar algorithm with O(n) complexity, even though you have nested loops, see Knuth-Morris-Pratt. Like @waTeim said, the number of executions of the inner loop is bounded by N (at the worst case, it is exactly N in the last iteration of the outer loop indeed, but 0 on all other outer-iterations). Another way to understand this: the average number of pop's you can perform is <=1 (since the "average" number of push-es is 1, and you never 'pop' more than you 'push')

Answer (score 0):

To work out the order really you are looking at the worst case. You are correct that the nested loop is the cause for concern here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++){
```

This is immediately order N

```
    while (!previousIndex.isEmpty() && a[previousIndex.peek()] <= a[i]){
```

This could potentially also go nearly N times.

So the final order is `N*N` or `N^2`

You do have to keep in mind the usual case though. If it is likely that the while loop will in fact exit after only a couple of iterations you could get back down to `O(N)`.

Comment: It is still not o(n), as you described previously, you probably meant to write the omega sign....

Comment: @steve. If the inner while loop only ever goes back 1 or 2 steps then the overall algorithm is `O(N)`. If the number of steps it goes back increases as N increases then it starts moving from `O(N)` to `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are fine and have an O(N) algorithm - but it's harder to prove than most. This assumes, though, that `.isEmpty()`, `.peek()` etc. on the `ArrayDeque` are all constant-time operations. Consult the documentation to be sure.

The key is that your processing of the `deque` in the inner loop is destructive:

```
while (!previousIndex.isEmpty() && a[previousIndex.peek()] <= a[i]){
    previousIndex.pop();
}
```

This removes an element from `previousIndex` each time, and can only run when there is one to remove. Therefore, the **total** number of times the `while` loop could run, across all indices, is the number of times that something is `.push`ed into deque. And since this only happens at one point - at the end of the first `for` loop - we can see that the number of items pushed is O(N).

Comment: That was my thought process... but at the end of the for loop, lets say the array a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7] wouldn't when at 7. the stack would then look 5 4 3 2 1 with 1 being the last item on the stack. We would go through the stack until it is empty, which is n-1 times....

Comment: Each time "through the stack" is assumed to be constant-time (the `.isEmpty()` and `.peek()` checks); and if those values are present in the stack to be removed now, then they must not have been removed previously. On those other iterations, we would have looked at the stack once, discovered that `a[previousIndex.peek()] > a[i]`, and moved on. We're concerned with the *total* number of pushes, pops etc. across the entire process.

Comment: That said, it would be much *simpler* to just store a single value representing the biggest value seen thus far. :)